# Ajax - best technique for processing large amount of data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I would like to know, what's the best method to retrieve and use a large amount of dynamic data.

For example:
I have a big website with a lot of fields, which dynamically create popups. The popups are created with a Javascript template engine, which needs JSON encoded data.

Now what I can do:

- Every time i request a popup, the client fetches the JSON data via AJAX
- I can create a Javascript var via PHP, which stores the data for all possible popups in the HTML code
- Or I can fetch the data via AJAX and cache it, in a Javascript var

So which one of these is the best one?
What are the disadvantages of them?
Or how would you attach/load the data for these popups?

BTW does anybody know why all the facebook popups are so smooth? It seems that they are created asynchronously, but they are so fast - like they were already embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-emptive caching.

Basically your 'pop-ups' (god knows why you have so many - there must be a better way :-D hehe) will have a pattern or logical order or whatever.

Using a combination of:

Loading the Main / Most likely to be first used pop-ups data and storing that in a var.

I would highly recommend trying to do this with JSON or similar and store data for 10-20 pop-ups together - downside is performance - have to parse whole file for 1 pop-up (but modern browsers / PCs - not much issue) - plus side number of http requests - the killer of site speed.

You COULD** start loading data for a button etc. on HOVER (as well as click) - milliseconds make prizes you know!

Finally - just ajax the data in and keep it small - the more you can strip out of the ajax call and pre-load (image sprites on page load etc. etc.) the faster your site will respond.

However without knowing:

- how often the data will update
- what sort of data you are sending (is it all graphs, all text etc.)
- how many of these pop-ups you have
- how often a new pop-up will be loaded
- what device(s) you users will be using
- etc.

I can only give wild stabs in the dark!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same thing now and find a good introduction blog http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript, hope it can give you some suggestions.